# Database content cache for used it in form dropdown list

Tags: yii

I want to cache the database content in yii and used that data in Yii drop down list. In the dropdownlist want to load the country names from database. (Have 2 tables user and country). In user form need the drop down list. That selected from country table using cache. Where queries are placed and when we can use the cache result in the user form?

Answer (score 1):

In order to cache the results from a table and then use that in a dropdown you'll need to first set up caching in your config file as described in the [Caching Overview](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.overview) of the Definitive Guide. If you wanted to use memCache you could set it up like so;

```
array(
    ......
    'components'=>array(
        ......
        'cache'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.caching.CMemCache',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Yii can use a number of difference caches which are listed in the Caching Overview link above.

You'll then need to make use of Yii's [data caching](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.data#query-caching) features. You can just do this in your user/_form.php view, for example;

```
...

echo $form->dropDownList($model,'country_id',CHtml::listData(Country::model()->cache(1000)->findAll(),'id','name'));

...
```

But the more MVC way would be to do this in your controller, something like so would work;

In your UserController:

```
...

public function actionUpdate()
{
    ...

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'countryList=>Country::model()->cache(1000)->findAll();,
    );
}

...
```

In your user/update.php view:

```
...

echo $this->renderPartial('_form', array('model'=>$model,'countryList'=>$countryList));

...
```

In your user/_form.php view:

```
...

echo $form->dropDownList($model,'country_id',CHtml::listData($countryList,'id','name'));

...
```

The examples above use no dependency for the cache, so the cached values will stay valid until the time (in this case 1000 seconds) expires.

To read more about using a cache dependency, you can read the [Cache Dependency](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.data#cache-dependency) section of the Data Caching doc.

[**EDIT**]

If you need to install memcached, and are using xampp on Windows, this is a great guide to get it working: [HOW TO INSTALL MEMCACHED ON XAMPP ON WINDOWS 7](http://www.leonardaustin.com/technical/how-to-install-memcached-on-xampp-on-windows-7)

Comment: include(Memcache.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory         This warning exist..

Comment: Hi @Aneesh, updated my answer with a link to installing memcached, I'm assuming you're using xampp on Windows 7...